# to_string with generic argument

Tags: generics, rust

I have the following generic function and now want to convert any given type if possible to a string.

```
fn write_row<T>(row: T) {
    let s: String = row.to_string();
}
```

But this will obviously not work because to_string is not implemented for the type T.

So my question is how would I check for the type of the argument and then apply to_string if needed and how can I tell the compiler that I now know that the variable is a defined type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tell the compiler that `T` must implement the [`ToString`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/string/trait.ToString.html) trait like this:

```
use std::string::ToString;

fn write_row<T: ToString>(row: T) {
    let s: String = row.to_string();
}
```

Comment: Great, but what would I do if I also want to allow strings which have no to_string method...

Comment: @TM90 What do you mean? There is no need to call `to_string` if it is a string...

Comment: I mean if i want to allow also a string for the write_row method and then skip the to_string part

Comment: @TM90 Calling `to_string` is harmless on a string. Don't add any more complexity by trying to check types.

Comment: BTW, I believe that is more idiomatic to use `Display` bound instead of `ToString`. The latter is only an auxiliary trait which provides convenient `ToString` function, while the former provides the core conversion functionality. `ToString` has a blanket implementation for all `Display` types. Additionally you will be able to use `Display` types in formatting macros: `format!("{}", row)`.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev Good idea. I still am learning these traits myself :).